# How do I make my USB DVD drive show up when I run a windows XP program on virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox, dvd

When I plug in my portable dvd drive to my laptop usb, it shows up with the disc being read. But as soon as I start my windows xp program on virtualbox, it disappears. I’m not sure how to fix this as the first time I tried this, the drive showed up on the virtualbox and I was able to run the game. I played for about 10 minuets then I closed the program and restarted my computer to fix a sound issue. Now the drive disappears every time I run the virtualbox program and I don’t know why. So I know it is possible to have them work together, just not sure how to get back to where I was since I changed nothing.

Comment: I read somewhere that someone made and .ISO file of a disc of Linux and went to storage devices, controller IDE and host drive to add that and the disc showed up in their program but I have no idea how to make that kind of file. Or if it is even possible to make one for a game that required a disc (drive and one that is being read by the computer) in order to be played.

Comment: Now the CD drive is showing up in the windows xp virtualbox but the disc isn’t being read and I have still changed nothing. I just continue to unplug and plug back the dvd/cd drive and reinsert the disc.

Answer (score 0):

In VirtualBox click on the settings for the VM you are using.  Then under storage, select the physical drive that you are going to use.  Then select the checkbox for Passthrough that will allow the drive to work in both the VM and the host OS.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: So I have done that, I select host drive because that is the only available one. I check the pass through and run my program. As soon as I do, the drive disappears still from host and my vm. Is it fixable?

Comment: @haley This is the only way that I know of on how to get the drive to show up in both.  Make sure that in the Attributes Optical Drive drop down that you have selected your USB drive there first, then it will appear in the Storage Devices box instead of the virtual drive.  You might also want to check your CD/DVD that you are putting into the drive that it doesn't have any finger prints or deep scratches, etc that can cause the disc not to read well.

Comment: I just realized that when I go to storage section, it says controller IDE, not SATA. How do I change that to see if that would fix the problem?

Comment: @haley At the bottom of the Storage Devices box in settings there, the first icon on the left is the Add new storage controller.  Click that and select Add SATA Controller.